Unable to Retrieve Contact ID from Local Storage Across Different Systems in Salesforce Lightning Web Component
I am currently working on a Salesforce Lightning Web Component (LWC) where I am using local storage to store the contact ID. The local storage works fine for storing the contact ID within the same system. However, when the same component is opened in another system, the contact ID is not being retrieved from the local storage.
I am using the following approach to store and retrieve the contact ID:
localStorage.setItem('contactId', contactId);
const contactId = localStorage.getItem('contactId');

What do you mean by "system"? Do you mean browser or do you mean org?

On the assumption you mean across orgs, this is intended behaviour. See the LWS Distortion Viewer for details around how storage API is distorted to ensure separation.
This ensures that data for one org does not leak over to another.
Note too that contact IDs would be org specific.
If you meant browser, then understand that local storage is within that browser on a given computer and is not shared across browsers or host computers.

we are just using the same login.
Actually we are implementing one timer that component we are added on record detail page.
So after start the timer then timer should be running on any system on same page and we are using the same login for every system.

What do you mean by "system"?

means on other laptop

As I said, the local storage is in the browser and the specific device. It is not shared. See sfdcfox's answer to your new question.
